# Can't connect to Ethernet on 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, ethernet

I recently started to dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. However, I can't connect to the internet over my ethernet port. I'm using a Gigabyte GA-H97M-D3H Micro ATX LGA1150 mobo, which has a Realtk PCIe GBE Ethernet controller. I've tried to install the drivers, but it gives me an error (I don't remember what it is exactly. On Windows ATM). Any ideas?

Comment: Doesnt your mainboard have a regular lan port?

Answer (score 1):

Check (vi/nano) **/etc/network/interfaces** I willing to bet you only have lo interface.

If so run **dmesg | grep "eth0"** it may tell you that eth0 has been changed to new name, then you will have to add the new interface name to **/etc/network/interfaces**.

If above does not work try **ifconfig** to see if there is a new name.

hope this helps!!